# Dirichlet parameters influence on samples

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If I draw samples from a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $[0.1, 0.1, \dotsc, 0.1]$, I get samples like multinomial, but if I set parameters to $[100, 100, \dotsc, 100]$, I'll get uniform distribution. Why would this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more of context? For example: How are you "drawing samples"? If you're doing this from a theoretical point of view, could you add your calculations or a reference? If you're doing this through simulations, could you tell us which computer algebra system are you using and add your code?

Comment: I used matlab and this code for sample generation
function r = drchrnd(a,n)
% take a sample from a dirichlet distribution
p = length(a);
r = gamrnd(repmat(a,n,1),1,n,p);
r = r ./ repmat(sum(r,2),1,p);
for parameter [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1] I got result like [ 0.9104    0.0000    0.0895    0.0001] and for parameters [100 100 100 100] , [ 0.2566    0.2583    0.2632    0.2218] and I don't know why?! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the magnitude of the parameters determines how concentrated the results are.  As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#String_cutting) puts it, "The variance around [the] mean varies inversely with $\alpha_0$," the first parameter (e.g., 0.1 or 100).

Compare the upper-right and lower-left images of Dirichlet draws below ([Frigyik et al., 2010](http://mayagupta.org/publications/FrigyikKapilaGuptaIntroToDirichlet.pdf), Fig. 4 on pg. 10, purple outlines added):

[image: image of draws]

The larger the $\alpha$ values, the closer to uniform are the string lengths.  By the time you get up to [100, 100, ..., 100] in your example, the variance is very low, so the draws are very close to uniform in result.